# How to rewrite function from php to JS with a lot of regex

Tags: php, javascript, regex, url-rewriting

I have a function in php which makes web friendly links. Now I want to write same function in JS, so I can make friendly url on fly. Here is function:

```
<?php 
function clearText($s)
{

  $s = trim($s);
  $s = strtr($s, 'ĘÓĄŚŁŻŹŃęóąśłżźćń', 'EOASLZZCNeoaslzzcn');
  $s = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]/", "", $s);
  $s = preg_replace("/\s[\s]+/", " ", $s);
  $s = preg_replace("/\s/", "_", $s);
  $s = strtolower($s);


  return $s;
}


function imageReplace($s)
{
  $s = clearText($s);
  $s = substr($s, 0, 64);
  return $s;
}

?>
```

Comment: Neither are we here to flame. Help or be quiet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function clearText(s)
{
  s = trim(s);
  s = strtr(s);   //follow this link http://obvcode.blogspot.in/2008/05/strtr-for-javascript.html
  var re = /[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]/;
  s = s.replace(re,"");
  s = s.replace(/\s[\s]+/, " ");
  s = s.replace(/\s/, "_");
  s = s.toLowerCase();

  return s;

}

function trim(str)
{
    var str2 = str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
    return str2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the regexes are your concern, they shouldn't be. Javascript regex engine is going to do the job just as well as php, just slightly different syntax. For instance, on your first replace instead of:

```
$s = preg_replace("/[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]/", "", $s);
```

you would have

```
s = s.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z\s]/, "");
```